# Scheme - string-append two lists of string

Tags: scheme, racket

I am trying to append two lists of string

but I do not know how to add space between two words.

```
(define (string-concat lst1 lst2)
        (map string-append lst1 lst2)
)
(string-concat '("elementary") "(school))
```

then result as "elementaryschool"

How can I add space when they merge? 
I've tried to using lambda but it does not work such as

```
(map string-append (cdr (append* (map (lambda (x) list " " x)) lst1)) lst2)
```

Comment: `(lambda (x) list " " x)` when called evaluates the variable `list`, then it evaluates `" "` and then it evaluates `x` which is the result of the function as it is in tail position.  Since there are no side effects involved it does the same as the identity function `(lambda (x) x)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `add-between` to add put spaces between your strings:

```
> (add-between '("This" "and" "that") " ")
'("This" " " "and" " " "that")
```

To append strings in a list, use `string-append*`

```
> (string-append* '("This" " " "and" " " "that"))
"This and that"
```

Your function becomes:

```
 (define (string-concat lst1 lst2)
     (string-append* (add-between (append lst1 lst2) " ")))
```

where `append` is used to combine the two lists into one.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply add a space in-between the two strings, `string-append` accepts multiple arguments:

```
(string-append "hello" " " "world")
=> "hello world"
```

Or you could use `string-join`:

```
(string-join '("hello" "world"))
=> "hello world"
```

Now, to extend this to lists of strings:

```
(map (lambda (s1 s2) (string-append s1 " " s2))
     '("a" "b" "c")
     '("1" "2" "3"))
=> '("a 1" "b 2" "c 3")

(map (lambda (s1 s2) (string-join (list s1 s2)))
     '("a" "b" "c")
     '("1" "2" "3"))
=> '("a 1" "b 2" "c 3")
```

Comment: how about when the user provides input?

Comment: You put the code in a function and pass the input as parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Another way you can do it using [match](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/match.html)

```
#lang racket

(define (add-between sep xs)
  (match xs
    ;; at least two items
    ((list a b rest ...)
     (string-append a sep (add-between sep (cons b rest))))

    ;; one item
    ((list a)
     a)

    ;; no items
    (null "")))

(add-between "~" '())                ;; ""
(add-between "~" '("a"))             ;; "a"
(add-between "~" '("a" "b"))         ;; "a~b"
(add-between "~" '("a" "b" "c"))     ;; "a~b~c"
(add-between "~" '("a" "b" "c" "d")) ;; "a~b~c~d"
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use string-append when you have multiple strings to append.

Use `with-output-to-string`

```
#lang racket

(define (string-concat lst1 lst2)
  (with-output-to-string
    (lambda ()
      (map
       (lambda (item1)
         (printf "~a " item1))
       lst1)
      (map
       (lambda (item2)
         (printf "~a " item2))
       lst2))))

(string-concat '("cat" "kitten") '("dog" "puppy"))
```

result:

```
"cat kitten dog puppy "
```